# How to do this diagram using xymatrix?

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

How can I do a diagram like this

[image]

using xymatrix? I don't want the diagram to extend for three lines (otherwise I could do the abo above diagram easily).

Comment: Can you post what you've already done, as a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the arrow tips and the spacing between rows and columns.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
%\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy} % to use cm arrow tip

\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@C=1cm{x\ar[r]^{a} & y} \qquad
\xymatrix{\ar@{|->}[r]^{T} & }   \qquad
\begin{gathered}
\xymatrix@C=1cm@R=1cm{F(x)\ar[r]^{F(a)}\ar[d] & F(y) \ar[d] \\ G(x)\ar[r]_{G(a)} & G(y) } 
\end{gathered}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]